Create an app which show a table in the beginning, If I click on a table row, it should give me the details of that row in another table
I want to create an app in microsoft power apps, which should show a table in the beginning, If I click on a table row, it should give me the details of that row in another table.
First opening table data should come from a rest API, and then looking up to one of the ID's from first table, there should be a details table in data verse which should show the data, we should have a form which will add the data in second table when submitted.
My question is what should I be using for this, either a canvas app or model driven app and since need to call an api as well, what should be my approach for this one app using microsoft power apps.

This type of open-ended question is better suited for the Power Platform community, not for StackOverflow (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for good types of questions for this site)
